# Trying to get the current date from the server with an AJAX partial-page postback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok, so I've got my HTML body, and other items in it. But what I am required to do is to use ajax to get the date and not do a full postback otherwise I would just use some PHP code.

I have a helper class - date.php

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
echo date("Y/m/d"); }
```

And the main body of my code using jQuery is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#lblDate').text(getDate());
    });

    function getDate() {
        $.ajax( {
            type: "GET",
            url: 'date.php',
            success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById('lblDate').innerHTML = "The date is " + data;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I've put that in my HTML code, but I'm not sure why it is not showing the date. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: write die; after echo date("Y/m/d");  this

Comment: Like, `echo date("Y/m/d"); die;` ? If so, doesn't work. I'm not exactly sure if the HTML body is even calling anything related to the function.

Comment: why is your script inside the same `<script>` tag with your external jquery?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're meaning.

Comment: what i mean is leave the external jquery script empty, then take out your custom script in a separate script tag

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really know much about jQuery, so should I put those two bodies in separte scripts?

Comment: its not a jquery issue, `<script src="jquery cdn path"></script><script>your script goes here!</script>`

Comment: Ok, I've done that, but still no date on my page.

Comment: change your script like this$(document).ready(function() {
        getDate();
    });

Comment: Awesome, it works, thanks so much!!

Comment: glad the issue fixed.accept the answer so that others can find their answer easily@user176312